# How to use google calendar api in android?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Hi all I am new to android. I parsed the calendar file. I need to add events to Google calendar from my application. I am using eclipse ide. In eclipse how to use the Google calendar api? Any jar file is needed  to use the calendar api?

Comment: Have you got your API key from google ?If not then first you have to get Google calendar API key

Answer (score 5):

use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", eventStartInMillis);
intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);
startActivity(intent);
```

also discussed here [How to launch Android Calendar application using Intent (Froyo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373074/how-to-launch-android-calendar-application-using-intent-froyo)
Also, This might not work perfectly on some devices, such as the endTime wont work on HTC wildfire.

Answer (score 1):

As of ICS release there is an official API for managing calendar data:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html