# I want to open up the Calendar application from an android application

Tags: android, android-activity, calendar

I want to open up the Calendar application from an android application. When i searched online, all i got this code.but it didn't work the below android 2.1.
Is it possible to launch Calender application from an android application below 2.1? If possible, could someone please help me with it.

```
Calendar tempCal = (Calendar) mCalendar.clone();
    tempCal.set(year, month, day); 
    Intent calendarIntent = new Intent() ;
    calendarIntent.putExtra("beginTime", tempCal.getTimeInMillis());
    calendarIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    calendarIntent.setClassName("com.android.calendar","com.android.calendar.AgendaActivity");
    startActivity(calendarIntent);
```

Comment: This is not valid approach to open standard Android activity using class name. You should use generic Intent. Check this for correct approach (not sure if that will work below 2.2): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373074/how-to-launch-android-calendar-application-using-intent-froyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  

intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");

intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");

intent.putExtra("beginTime", eventStartInMillis);

intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 4):

I also recommend this:
[How to launch Android Calendar application using Intent (Froyo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373074/how-to-launch-android-calendar-application-using-intent-froyo)

Answer (score 0):

To launch the activity for adding an event to the calendar, use:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event"); 
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTimeInMilliseconds); 
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endTimeInMilliseconds);

    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    startActivity(intent);
```