# How can I build a custom calender control for android application?

Tags: android

I have an application in which I need to use a calender control. How do I get such a control for android?

I have heard of Ancal , but I don't know how to use it in my application.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get such a control for android?

Android 3.0 has a calendar control (CalendarView). Prior versions of Android do not.

> I have heard of Ancal , but I don't know how to use it in my application.

The [Ancal project](http://code.google.com/p/ancal/wiki/AnCal) is open source. However, it is an application, not a "calendar control". I am not aware of an open source "calendar control" for Android.

Comment: so the only way out is to make a custom gridview and call it a calendar.... that would be a whole lot of coding for me...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if your app needs to perform just basic calendar operations such as creating new events or viewing existing events it will be *much* easier to create intents to launch parts of the built-in calendar app. The activity stack system will ensure the user is returned to your app when the action is complete. Google for 'android calendar intent' or look at these SO questions for more details

[How to add calendar events in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android)

[How to launch Android Calendar application using Intent (Froyo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373074/how-to-launch-android-calendar-application-using-intent-froyo)

If you are happy to code up your own calendar controls you can read the built-in calendar data using an *undocumented* calendar data provider. I wrote an article about it on my blog here:

http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151

Comment: i have read your blog and have bookmarked the link also :-)...but i want the calendar to have certain features that i want...so pass around control via intents is not possible...i have heard that android 3.0 has a inbuilt calender widget..like an edittext, button etc. i want such a widget /library for my phone based project working on android 2.1-2.3.